# How to write a formal email asking about availability for an interview

Tags: interviewing, email

My contract for an internship is ending in the sales department, and I would like to continue in the company in the PR department. Last friday, I talked with the PR manager, and she said she would email my resume to the other two PR specialists and have them schedule a time with me this week to talk to me, then they will compare notes and see if they want to hire me or not.

Yesterday was a holiday, and today is tuesday but I haven't had any contact yet, the PR specialists are usually quite busy. What is a short and formal way to ask the PR specialists when they might have time this week for the interview/talk?

Comment: Dear Sir/Madam,

Have you been able to look at your availability for the interview for the position in the PR department for myself?

Yours faithfully,
Anya

Comment: You said the PR specialists are quite busy. Work through your PR manager and follow up with her rather than contact them directly. If they don't know you and they know they're busy, you mean nothing to them and they'll get back to you when they get back to you. They cannot ignore their manager. You, they can ignore.

Comment: problem is pr manager is on vacation until next week, but i guess i'll wait one more day, All i know is that they know who i am but.... you are right....

Answer (score 3):

Don't jump the gun. You only talked with the manager on Friday, and given the weekend and the holiday it's now only the next day. Unless it's urgent that this happens really soon, give them a few days and if it doesn't happen after that, talk to the PR *manager*, not the specialists - it's the manager you've been communicating with so far.

Comment: tiny problem is that the manager is on vacation, i think maybe i'll wait until at least tomorrow. thanks!